# Always 404 error for dynamic content in IIS on localhost

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am trying to host a website on local IIS in Windows 7.

The version of IIS is 7.5. I have enabled every feature under IIS from Windows Feature.

My Web application is a ASP.NET MVC 5 application built in .NET 4.5.

I can host this application in my Windows 8 which is IIS 8.5.

Here is a screenshot if I visit home page of my web application.

[image]

And this is whenever I try to visit anything like `/Home/Index`

[image]

I have replicate followings as it was in my Windows 8 IIS 8.5 system.

[image]

[image]

Please help me running this site.

Comment: Hate to state the obvious, but where is the ASP.NET 4.5? We don't see this added to the ISAPI Filters?

Comment: @ColdT ASP.NET 4.5 is never installed in a separate directory. See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/12070518/1306394